# How can I 'checkout' a previous commit's total file state into my current branch (without detaching or creating a new branch)

Tags: git

Can I "checkout" / copy the total file state at a previous time (by commit hash) as unstaged file changes into my current branch?

Comment: No, i want all files. And it isn't a reset because I'm trying to check out a previous state and have the difference as unstaged changes in the current branch.

Answer (score 1):

you could checkout:

```
git checkout some-revison-or-branch -- .
```

That will bring all of the files from that revision or branch into your working tree without moving from the currently checkout out branch.

Warning: **DANGEROUS**: If you also want to make sure that newer files are deleted, then you could do a removal of all files and then run the checkout.

Comment: Note, however, that this form of `git checkout` makes them *staged* (copies the specified revision's files to *both* the index *and* your work-tree). If you have Git 2.23 or later, the `git restore` command is capable of copying from commit to work-tree without overwriting the index copy, leaving these unstaged (the index copy will continue to match whatever was in the index before).

Comment: Still need to play with restore